# Once I get or once I'll get?

Tags: tenses

English isn't my native language, just letting you guys know. I can't wrap my head around about which is the correct form. *Once I get* or *once I'll get*?
For example: *Once I get my car fixed, I'll go*.

Answer (score 6):

In the section **tense simplification in subordinate clauses**, Swan (*Practical English Usage*, p573) states:

> If the main verb of a sentence makes it clear what kind of time the
>   speaker is talking about, it is not necessary for the same time to be
>   indicated again in subordinate clause.

**Go** is the main verb in the sentence *Once I get my car fixed, I'll go*. It is used with a future construction (*will*), so there is no need for the verb in the subordinate clause (*get*) to use the same future construction.

Swan notes further, with relevance to the OP's example:

> Present tenses are often used instead of **will + infinitive** to refer to
>   the future in subordinate clauses.

Swan's examples include:

> - I'll write to her when I have time. (not ... <strike>when I will have
>     time.</strike>)
> - I'll go where you go.

So in summary, the grammatical form here is:

> Once I get my car fixed, I'll go.

or, reversing the clauses:

> I'll go once I get my car fixed.